# easy_admin : Configuring the Logged In User Information

Tags: easyadmin, symfony-4.3

In the easy_admin view, there is a fontawesome with "user unnamed".

I would like to have the name of the login user. 
I configured config/packages/easy_admin.yaml like this (name is the propoerty of User that I want to display:

```
    entities:
      user:
        class: App\Entity\User
        display_name: true
        name_property_path: 'name'
```

I still have "unnamed user" instead of the name of the login user. Do you have a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue. Please try this:

```
easy_admin:
    user:
        display_name: true
        name_property_path: email
```

`user` needs to be set under easy_admin section.